# How to get a screen capture at double resolution?

Tags: android, andengine

If your phone's display size is 320x480, then AndEngine performs screenCapture() at the same 1:1 resolution.

I tried changing the surface size...
I tried generating the camera at double resolution...
I tried scaling the mRenderSurfaceView....

But, the screenCapture() will always save the file in 320x480 resolution, i.e. the resolution of actual device.

So can anyone help me to show how can I get a screen capture in double resolution ?

Comment: I doubt this is possible. The screen is generated at that resolution from the base parts, so I'm quite sure there are no extra 'versions' of it lying around for higher resolutions. You'd have to rebuild the screen for one (and so redoing any posts/actions that made the screen the way it is).

Comment: Hmm.. So how can I rebuild the scene at double resolution then ? I am not looking forward to delve into the dissection of AndEngine. It will be a lot of work. Because for that I will have to brush up myself fully on OpenGL ES. Some day I will, but not now! ;D

Comment: Well, If I knew more about andengine, I'd have supplied an answer instead of just a comment :). I suppose you could 'fake' the current resolution by trying to override the values that are used beforehand? Sorry I can't help you further, maybe some andengine hero comes along :)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10125458/android-andengine-screenshot-of-the-scene), it backs up that you can't screen shot what is not being rendered.

The alternative mentioned is to render to a RenderTexture of applicable size instead. That other question has an example.

Comment: @CodenameLambda1 I agree with Nick. In order to capture a true screenshot double the screen size, the user must be running a customized rom or kernel that renders the screen twice the size, but draws at half. I've never heard of something like this being done either as it's more busy-work for the GPU.